# Why use Blender Stack Exchange over Blender Artists Forums?

Tags: discussion

Why should users be using Blender Stack Exchange instead the support forum on Blender Artists?

*P.S (Would a moderator mind adding this to FAQ?)*

Comment: Because it's **STACK EXCHANGE!!**

Comment: Let's hold off on FAQing stuff until there's a bit more activity (and [site-mods](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/100/pro-tempore-moderator-nominations) to monitor it).

Comment: This site is much more useful to me, as a novice who just wants easily searched questions. I'm so glad it was created.

Answer (score 38):

Apart from the higher signal to noise ratio, and the format difference previously mentioned, I find that the Stack Exchange format is a lot more friendly towards people *seeking* information but not participating in the discussion.

e.g. drawing from my personal experiences with programming, before there was StackOverflow, researching a topic requires one to wade through pages and pages of forum posts to distill out the best ideas. While the same information is often presented on StackOverflow without the user even have to scroll down past the first screen.

The heavy participation of developers in Blender SE is also awesome. And I hope this continues.

BA is like a lounge, a good place for people to communicate.

SE is like a library, you come here to find the best answer to a particular question.

Comment: +1 for your analogy.

Answer (score 11):

The support on Blender Artists wasn't the greatest. Questions and answers were bloated and non-informative, and most questions were not answered. Blender Artist is a forum made more for conversation-like interaction(which is fine, it's just not optimal for Question/Answer format). Stack exchange cuts down on the excess and gets to the heart of the problem: Questions and Answers. It's the best way to get quick answers about Blender.

Comment: +1 I agree, the forums are more of a place to showcase artwork and a general discussion area. Alot of the questions asked here would have gotten lost in the mass of threads.

Comment: The correct name is Blender Artist **s**.

Comment: @RolandiXor yep, fixed it.

Comment: @iKlsR ergo, _a lot of questions have already been lost in the mass of threads_.

Answer (score 6):

StackExchange does a few things that BlenderArtists Forums doesn't.

- Edit posts that need a helping hand (formatting, spelling, content, title) if you have enough points.
- See a vote tally, which is the closest you'll get to an objectively graded answer.
- It has nice enough syntax highlighting for discussing code snippets.
- It uses markdown for markup, nice.
- Comments on answers appear directly beneath the answers, and therefore are associated directly with them.
- Heavier comment exchanges on a question or answer can turn into their own chat if things get lively.
- Answers don't get a chance to go stale, if they include inaccurate information someone (sufficiently bothered by it) will pick up on it and edit it for future searchers.

There's plenty more I'm sure, but these are the main reasons for me.

Answer (score 5):

You can sum it up with a section of the FAQ that says:

> "Just questions, just answers."

I say so because on forums, you tend to get a lot of unrelated noise, to a level way beyond what you get in the comments (which can be flagged and cleaned up easily, or voted up when they count). Comments have a tendency to devolve quickly into unrelated banter; StackExchange questions tend to stick to the point.

Forums are not often kept up to date, an no one but the OP of a post or the forum mods usually has editing rights; on StackExchange, anyone can edit and anyone can keep things up to date where it matters.

Answer (score 4):

StackExchange is a curated and evolving knowledge base that can be edited and improved by users who strive to fine tune information. I have personally gained quite a lot since the time i joined it.