# Canonical posts for hardware questions?

Tags: discussion

As stated in [Answering vague support questions (once)?](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181/answering-vague-support-questions-once/184#184), we should consider having some "canonical posts" for some hardware posts.

Some examples of topics which might benefit from a canonical post:

## Problems enabling GPU for cycles:

We get a [large number of questions asking about enabling cycles GPU rendering](https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=cuda%20is:question).

We could have a canonical answer which covers installing cuda and system drivers (for linux, mac, and windows)

For example, these questions could be answered in a single canonical answer covering common GPU render issues:

- [Cannot change to GPU Rendering](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/7379/599)
- [Installing CUDA for Blender Cycles on Ubuntu 12.04](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/2926/599)
- [macbook pro rendering issue](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/7458/599)

---

**Update:** A canonical post has been added [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/7485/599).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think we should have one answer for all of the cuda problems for all supported OS (windows, linux (Debian based, Arch Linux) and Mac). We should have a guide for all of these even though it does not fit the question format for the site. Than we could just mark every future question as a duplicate and be done with it.

Comment: Should this be done with an existing Q, or should a new Q be created specially?

Comment: I agree with this, this is not in our scope so a giant cw post should quell this. I think a new post factoring  in what all the previous posts asked and contained should be fine.