# How could I set up a question that collects Blender+Python tutorials?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

I know how to program somewhat well, but am completely new to Blender. I need to use Blender to generate some geometry, and had a bit of a tough time finding tutorials that give me the quickest (i.e. not the most in-depth) route to get going with some simple modelling using Python.

This is something useful I have found so far (you'll have to scroll down for tutorial 0 -- the first tutorial):

- http://science-o-matics.com/tag/how-to+blender+python/?lang=en

However, I am sure there are other such tutorials (each with their pros and cons), and I am wondering if there would be interest in creating an updateable list of them that can be generally referred to? So, this would be a community wiki type of thing.

How can/should I best title/form such a question on the main Blender SE?

Comment: Collecting useful links is well outside the scope of stackexchange sites. [http://www.slant.co] started recently and is intended for this purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Such a question will be closed, you'll have more luck on [BlenderArtists.org](http://blenderartists.org/), where the community guidelines are less strict.

Furthermore, I have found that there is a general absence of Blender python tutorials. Here are some good ones though: https://cgcookie.com/blender/category/tutorials/scripting/.

Answer (score 3):

We've had [a discussion like this already](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/410/599), and it was decided to make [one big post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/15355/599) with answers for each category.

I think a list of python tutorials would fit right in as an answer [there](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/15355/599).

In addition, we also had an [older post of a similar type](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/40/599) on meta, which may also be of interest.